# Writing to same file concurrently delay

Tags: c#, file

I am using a socket server program which works asynchronously. I need to write the incoming packets to a  single file. There are hundreds of clients connected at a time and can write the file concurrently. Here is the code that writes the received packet to file...

```
static ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
signal.WaitOne();
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
       sw.WriteLine(message);
signal.Set();
```

The problem is that it's slowing down the next data packet to be received.

Comment: opening and closing the stream is going to hurt a bit, cant you leave it open and append to it?

Comment: Is there any way to update file instantly?

Comment: sw.Flush(), but writing instantly will slow you down even more...as StreamWriter is buffered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decouple your reading and writing. You can do this by using queues.

Create a single thread-safe message queue ([`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) springs to mind).

Clients push messages into the queue.

Have a **single** writer that pops messages from the queue and commits each message in turn to disk (concurrent file IO from multiple threads is usually a performance killer anyway).

Now, the only synchronisation you need is taken care of by the queue, so it nicely eliminates a potential source of deadlock/blocking, and both ends of the consumer/producer chain are able to work at top speed.

Alternatively, take a look at [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's built for these sorts of producer/consumer situations. It's a worthy investment of your time.

Comment: +1 `ConcurrentQueue` is a nice option as he can take items from the queue without hurting his incoming data other than having to synchronize it as `ConcurrentQueue` is FIFO.

Comment: thanks for reply. I'll try ConncurrentQueue for quick solution and will explore TPL DataFlow for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you receive data. If you do as I think, then simple run logging operation asynchronously (fixing your code):

```
// define this somewhere to lock access to "path" file
private readonly object _lock = new object();

Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                sw.WriteLine(message);
        }
    });
```